# iOS 9 - LocationManager updating locations too frequently

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location, cllocationmanager, ios9

I am migrating an existing app to work with iOS 9, there was not much to change but adding ATS to the `info.plist` and use `MKAnnotationView` instead of `MKPinAnnotationView` for custom pins on the map. The problem was when starting to test the changes, I noticed the location updates were too frequent, even when I'm standing still. Nothing has been changed in the way the location manager is initialized.

Here is a small sample of the log.

```
2015-09-25 12:16:25.462 MyApp[2009:911066] location: <+39.09040164,-77.52540765> +/- 65.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 9/25/15, 12:16:25 PM Eastern Daylight Time 

2015-09-25 12:16:25.464 MyApp[2009:911066] location: <+39.09040164,-77.52540765> +/- 65.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 9/25/15, 12:16:25 PM Eastern Daylight Time 

2015-09-25 12:16:25.468 MyApp[2009:911066] location: <+39.09040164,-77.52540765> +/- 65.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 9/25/15, 12:16:25 PM Eastern Daylight Time 

2015-09-25 12:16:25.475 MyApp[2009:911066] location: <+39.09040164,-77.52540765> +/- 65.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 9/25/15, 12:16:25 PM Eastern Daylight Time
```

The location manager is set like this

```
    locationManager = [CLLocationManager new];

    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = 25.0f;
    [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];

    if ([locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)]) {
       [locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    }
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

I guess the question is: is there something wrong with my implementation or was there a change in the Core Location API that is ignoring the distance filter?

Comment: Is the property `pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically` on `CLLocationManager` set to `YES`? If set to `YES`, it helps improving the battery life by disabling location updates if the location data is unlikely to change.

Comment: @MatteoPacini It is never set to `NO` at any point in code, the default value is `YES`. I'll try explicitly setting it to `YES`. Thanks.

Comment: @MatteoPacini I tried it, didnt make any difference. thanks tho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:` method the `distanceFilter` property of `CLLocationManager` was was being reset depending on the speed, in `iOS 9` this seems to trigger a new location update (returning the last known location),  thus resulting on hundreds of new location updates in a few seconds.

Comment: Interesting. As soon as you are able you should accept your own answer so other readers know the problem is solved.

Comment: I see the same kind of results but I'm not changing anything to the locationmanager after starting it. Can you have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32838488/cllocationmanager-in-ios9-giving-incorrect-locations-ios8-is-ok perhaps ?

Comment: @SjoerdPerfors I think our issues with `CLLocationManager` are a little different, my problem wasn't related to bad location data, but **extremely** frequent updates.